# Use string concatenation in UPDATEXML()

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write an update script for my oracle db. I want to replace old XML node values with new ones. But I need to do this for *many* values so I wanna outsource the logic in a procedure.

This is what I've come up with.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
    old_name IN NVARCHAR2, 
    new_name IN NVARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        MY_TABLE
    SET
        ENTITY = UPDATEXML(ENTITY, '/*/Section', '<Section>' || new_name || '</Section>', 'xmlns="http://foo.bar.com/baz"')
    WHERE
        EXTRACTVALUE(ENTITY, '/*/Section', 'xmlns="http://foo.bar.com/baz"') = old_name;
END;
```

This is actually working really well - when I don't use string concatenation in `UPDATEXML()`. When I start using concatenation the execution of the procedure stops working / starts to throw exceptions.

I've also tried `CONCAT(CONCAT('<Section>', new_name), '</Section>')` instead of the `||`-Operator. Didn't work out either.

The exception I get running the procedure in *Oracle SQL Developer*

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
> PLS-00905: object MY_DB.MY_PROCEDURE is invalid
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action: